# Android + Create Fragment in ViewPager and show as Popup

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, popup

I am new into Android and I like to code. I just got the requirement to show the screen like this.

**[User Inerface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKBOI.jpg)**

My understanding is, there is an Activity which contains ViewPager and ViewPager having multiple Fragments which opened as Popup Dialog.
So I created **Activity** like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    private ViewPager viewPagerMain;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewByIds();
        setupImageSlider();
    }
    private void findViewByIds()
    {
        viewPagerMain = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerMain);
    }
    private void setupImageSlider()
    {
        viewPagerMain.setAdapter(new MyStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }
     static class MyStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {    
        public MyStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }    
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {              
            return OfferFragment.init();    
        }    
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

For now just to show dummy pages I am passing fix size as 4 in *getCount()*

Here is my OfferFragment class

```
public class OfferFragment extends Fragment {
    private View view;   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offer, container, false);
        return view;
    }
    public static OfferFragment init() {
        OfferFragment offersFragment = new OfferFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        offersFragment.setArguments(args);
        return offersFragment;
    }
}
```

Here are my some thoughts why I created *init()* method in Fragment class. As I don't know how many pages will have to be shown, in that case creating Fragment object may cause exception.

I know there is DialogFragment class which shows Fragment as Dialog. but in my case I am calling *init()* from Activity class and inside init() creating object of Fragment class.
So if I extend DialogFragment then, I have to call *setShowDialog()* method inside onCreate() of Fragment and it give me below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view
```

Kindly let me know how to Create Fragment in ViewPager and show as Popup

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Downvoted without any comment

Comment: please comment if you need any other info

Comment: "Kindly let me know how to show ViewPager inside Activity where ViewPager contains multiple Fragmant and opened as Popup Dialog. "-- from your question what do you want exactly?

Comment: ok, check the screen I have shared, I want to create a UI like that only.

Comment: I can not see any screenshot

Comment: actually I dont have 10 reputations, so I cannot paste image here directly in question. so thats why I provided the link. By the way I have explained what I have tried. I need a better approach to get it done.

Comment: Search for User Inerface

Comment: @SaidurRahman I have edited my question. please check it. and User Interface named link in there in my question description where you can find the image link